# Rubber Tree - Leaves Falling?

Tags: trees

Have Good Healthy leaves falling off - not sure what to do to stop it

Have not watered in a while and top soil seems still damp.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though old age has caught up with your rubber plant. There are many dying and withering shoots, branches with small leaves and signs that maybe your best bet is to start again. There may be no diseases or pests on the tree, it has just exhausted resources in the pot and could be in a location where it gets little light. It may be possible to go carefully through the branching system removing the dead and dying parts plus rejuvenating the root ball, but you will have a lot of sticky sap to deal with and the result is likely to be a very odd looking unbalanced plant which may not recover.

You might consider [air layering a few branches](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/help-for-the-home-gardener/advice-tips-resources/visual-guides/air-layering-a-dicot-plant.aspx) (Missouri botanic garden) that are still showing good large healthy leaves if the plant has sentimental value. However this could take some time if you don't have a sunny location for the rubber plant. It could be time to bite the bullet, compost the plant, find a replacement seedling and use the pot again when the time is right.